# algorithm Convert 365 days to day of month and month (Persian Calendar)

Tags: python, algorithm

hello every one i want to write an algorithm to convert a a number into day and month for example 60 means 30/2 using the **Persian calendar**.

Here is the code I found:

```
#1 Years = 12 month and 365 days
#Input
numday=int(input('Enter The Number [1 Until 365]: '))


if 0<numday<=186:
    month =numday // 31 +1
    day = numday % 31
    print(' Month: ', month, '\n'
          , 'Day: ', day,'\n'
          ,month,'/',day)

if 186<numday<=366:
    numday -= 186
    month = numday // 30 +1 +6
    day = numday % 30
    print(' Month: ', month, '\n'
          , 'Day: ', day, '\n'
          , month, '/', day)
```

but there is a problem for example with number 186 there should be another if because it should shows 31/6 not 0/7 i can not find a solution

Comment: why don't you just use [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Comment: @PaulLemarchand i want to write the algorithm of the code not the library

Comment: @nazanin77 Can you elaborate on *why* you want to re-invent the wheel here? With as many edge cases as there are in date/time processing, it'd be much more prudent to use something more tried & true.

Comment: `datetime` It's not a third party library, it's in the standard library, just like `random` or `string`.

Comment: @esqew I do not want to write a code I want to write the algorithm and show the process of converting the  number into month and date

Comment: @PaulLemarchand I understand what you say but I want to write the algorithm not a code

Comment: @nazanin77 I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. For example why the output would be 30/2? There are only 28 days in February.

Comment: @PaulLemarchand i am saying it in persian calender

Answer (score 1):

*disclaimer: this answer uses the Gregorian calendar, not the Persian calendar.*

## Using the standard library

Using module [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html): define a `datetime.date` object for January 1st, add a `datetime.timedelta` object with your input number of days, and check for month and day of the resulting `datetime.date` object.

```py
import datetime

def get_month_day(numday):
  d0 = datetime.date(2021,1,1)
  deltaT = datetime.timedelta(numday)
  d  = d0 + deltaT
  return d.month, d.day
```

## Using hardcoded arithmetic

Unfortunately, logic like `numday // 31 +1` in your code cannot possibly work. The reason is that some months have 31 days, some other months have 30 days, and february has only 28 days. Or 29.

We need to hardcode the number of days per month. Then we are going to accumulate those number of days, to have the number of days for the last day of each month; finally, we are going to compare our number of days to those numbers. We can use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate). If you are allergic to modules from the standard library, you can write your own `accumulate` function to get the cumulative sums of a list.

```py
import itertools

def get_month_day(numday):
  assert(0 <= numday < 365)
  month_lengths = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
  cumulative = list(itertools.accumulate(month_lengths, initial=0))
  for month, endofmonth_numday in enumerate(cumulative):
    if numday < endofmonth_numday:
      return month, numday - cumulative[month-1] + 1
```

Comment: OP said in a comment they are using the Persian calendar... which wasn't made clear at all in the post. This calendar has 31 days for the first 6 months, then 30 days for the rest and 29 days for the last month.

Comment: Okay then!! -_-

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you are using the Persian calendar... The correct way of rounding the month to the upper value is using `math.ceil`. Your day cannot be 0, so you need to set it to 31 instead when you use the modulo operator. Here is your code for the first 6 months with these 2 changes:

```
import math
numday = int(input('Enter The Number [1 Until 365]: '))
if 0 < numday <= 186:
    month = math.ceil(numday / 31)
    day = numday % 31
    if day == 0:
        day = 31
    print(' Month: ', month, '\n', 'Day: ', day, '\n', month, '/', day)
```

Output:

```
>>>186
Month:  6
Day:  31
6 / 31
```